# SharePoint Create List Item Targeting External List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have been trying for a couple of weeks to get this rolling and am pulling out what little hair I have left. I have a custom list and when an item gets added, I have a workflow set to create an item in an external list. So I associate the workflow with the custom list and target the external list. This is supposed to be possible. In SharePoint designer, I can target the external list by selecting a 2010 workflow but when it comes to mapping the fields, all I get is a blank list. I have tried the same operation using Visual Studio. There, it will not even let me target the external list. I have tried this in SharePoint Online as well as on-premises 2016 Sharepoint Server. I have tried using SP Designer and VS from my desktop as well as from installed on the server. I have all of the credentials I need - I am site admin/owner. There has got to be a small setup piece that I am missing because I have seen many posts where people have done exactly what I am describing and only a couple of posts where people have encountered the same issue I am having. In those cases, no meaningful help was ever offered. Hoping some kind soul reads this and passes on the key. Thanks!!!